# Got TS 2739 error while returning value from promise. Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

Currently I'm writing code for request login to server and receive it's session data and send to global context.

Basic principle is 1)Request and get Promise 2)Validate fetch result itself and response status. 3)Provide value to external component. And I'm working on 1) and 2).

But I got an error about data typing `Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'SessionInfo': userEmail, userName, sessionToken, duets(2739)` at code that returns result data to external components. Despite of strict data typing(Maybe I think), I'm not sure why linter says Promise not Promise>. I think TS fails to assert it's type.

When I run very similar code with Javascript(without typing), it works in past. I'm not sure why this happens and I don't know what's wrong. Can you check my code?

Codes are below, there's 4 files -- interface definition file related to User, interface definition for handling response json, Actual request fetch, Response validation and evaluation.

When I checked linting at `return res.data` at `actionHandler.ts`, linter succeed to predict it's type. `res.data` is `ResponseSet<SessionInfo>.data?: userTypes.SessionInfo` as linter said.

In `userTypes.ts`

```js
export interface SessionInfo {
    userEmail: string,
    userName: string,
    sessionToken: string,
    due: number,
}
```

In `commonTypes.ts`

```js
export interface ResponseSet<T> { // Response wrapper when it returns with code 200
    statusCode: ResponseStatusCode, // ResponseStatusCode is custom typed status code not for request it self.
    data?: T,
    description?: string,
};
```

In `userReq.ts`

```js
const login = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<commonTypes.ResponseSet<userTypes.SessionInfo>> => {
    try {
        const request: Request = new Request(
            composeUri(`user/login`, { email, password }),
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
                mode: 'cors',
            }
        );

        const response: Response = await fetch(request);
        if (response.status != 200) throw response.status;

        return await response.json();

    } catch {
        return {
            statusCode: 1,
        };
    }
}
```

In `actionHandler.ts`

```js
export const doLogin = (email: string, password: string): userTypes.SessionInfo => {
    const result: userTypes.SessionInfo = userReq.login(email, password)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.statusCode != 0) throw new Error(res.description || 'UnknownError');
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return null;
        });
    return result;
}
```

Where I got an error is `const result:...`. I got `Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'SessionInfo': userEmail, userName, sessionToken, due ts(2739)`. I'm not sure why it is recognized as 'Promise` despite of strict type definition of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that `result` isn't `SessionInfo`. It is a Promise of it.

```js
const result: Promisse<userTypes.SessionInfo | null>;
```

`doLogin` is async due to used promise, you should follow `async` `await` inside and it can't return `userTypes.SessionInfo`, result will be a promise.

```js
export const doLogin = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<userTypes.SessionInfo | null> => {
  try {
    const result: commonTypes.ResponseSet<userTypes.SessionInfo> = await userReq.login(email, password);
    if (res.statusCode != 0) throw new Error(res.description || 'UnknownError');
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
  return res.data;
}

// somewhere in the code (async env)
await doLogin(email, password);
```

Comment: I didn't give any response description, sorry. Result json comes with ResponseSet dtype. Which mean ```{statusCode: number, data: SessionInfo,, description: string} ``` so dont have to response.json inside the return structure. And one more, as I knew, response.json() returns Promise, is it okay to not await?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Might you try to case it like above?

Comment: I'll try now, I just see this answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, just updated it to have the same types as in your code.

Comment: Okay, now I got the real problem. `result` is a promise, and you need to work inside of `doLogin` like with promises.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a lot, but I still dont understand what is different between yours and mine. Can you explain for me? I already declare return type of Function properly but why linter behave like there's type mismatch?

Comment: I think you have an `any` restriction like `no-unsafe-any` or `no-any` and because `.json()` isn't typed correctly you need to do it yourself.